# How to obtain facebook notifications programatically in android applications

Tags: java, android, facebook

I want to include a functionality in my android app that shows or alerts the user if there are any unread notifications appear on facebook. I want to know if this is possible in android app to show unread notifications from facebook or just give a count of unread notifications.

Comment: Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

Comment: @EvZ I did and I found this link "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/notifications" but the problem is how can I get push notifications inside my app or just a count of unread notifications.

Comment: You can find the answer in the first 5 posts, good luck: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=android+dev+how+to+get+facebook+notifications&gws_rd=ssl